# JS Array property extraction

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-manipulation

I need to manipulate an array in order to use it with a graphic that accepts a specific shape of data.

Here is the current shape

```
[
{
Name:"Alfred",
French:15,
English:13,
Spanish:9
},

{
Name:"Robert",
French:5,
English:43,
Spanish:16
}
,

{
Name:"Jonathon",
French:15,
English:32,
Spanish:18
}
]
```

I Need to transform this array into this shape:

```
[
{
subject:"French",
Alfred:15,
Robert:5,
Jonathon:15
},

{
subject:"English",
Alfred:13,
Robert:43,
Jonathon:32
},

{
subject:"Spanish",
Alfred:9,
Robert:16,
Jonathon:18
}


]
```

My problem is that I can't extract the label of the subject once, and then fill the object. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested `forEach` loops, and build an object `all` with keys as `subject` and values as object with Name and value (score).

```js
const transform = (arr) => {
  const all = {};
  arr.forEach(({ Name, ...obj }) =>
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([subject, value]) => {
      all[subject] ??= { subject };
      all[subject][Name] = (all[subject][Name] ?? 0) + value;
    })
  );
  return Object.values(all);
};

data = [
  {
    Name: "Alfred",
    French: 15,
    English: 13,
    Spanish: 9,
  },

  {
    Name: "Robert",
    French: 5,
    English: 43,
    Spanish: 16,
  },
  {
    Name: "Jonathon",
    French: 15,
    English: 32,
    Spanish: 18,
  },
];

console.log(transform(data))
```

Comment: I found another way but it is more complicated, and less consistent than yours. Thank you very much for the simplicity!

Answer (score 0):

I have no doubt that there are cleaner ways to do this but this seems to produce the results you want.

```
const data = [
    {
        Name: "Alfred",
        French: 15,
        English: 13,
        Spanish: 9
    },
    {
        Name: "Robert",
        French: 5,
        English: 43,
        Spanish: 16
    },
    {
        Name: "Jonathon",
        French: 15,
        English: 32,
        Spanish: 18
    }
];

const subjects = ["French", "English", "Spanish"];
const people = data.map((person) => person.Name);

const newData = [];

subjects.forEach((subject, index) => {
    const o = {subject: subjects[index]};

    people.forEach(person => {
        o[person] = data.find(record => record.Name === person)[subject];
    });

    newData.push(o);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Jay !